# Twisted Deferred pattern to protect an uninitialised database

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

How should I protect a database from being accessed before it is initialized?

I have a database.  It needs to be initialized.  This may take time and so initialization returns a Deferred.  Let's call this deferred `d_db_ready`.

I have other methods, say `read_a_value_from_the_database()`, that would like to access the database, but only after it has been initialized.

Easy!  I add a callback to `d_db_ready`:

```
d_value = d_db_ready.addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database)
```

Now, the value I desired from the database can be found in the Deferred `d_value`.

Let's try to do it again:

```
d_value2 = d_db_ready.addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database)
```

This time it doesn't work.  This is because the callback chain for `d_db_ready` now finishes with the value we read from the database.  It no longer gives access to the database.

What pattern should be used here instead?  How should I protect the database from being accessed before it is initialized?

One option would be for `read_a_value_from_the_database` to return the database... but then it wouldn't be returning the value.  Further, such an approach is a certain source of a horrible potential bug: when I forget to return the database I'd have to chase down which function was previously called, when all I'd have would be the function that's currently calling.

Below is some runnable code to demonstrate my question:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

database = "uninitialized"

d_db_ready = Deferred()

def init_database():
    global database
    print("Initializing database")
    database = { "value": 1 }
    d_db_ready.callback(database)

def read_a_value_from_the_database(db):
    value = db["value"]
    print("value:", value)
    return value

d_db_ready.addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database)

d_db_ready.addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database) # <--- errors

init_database()
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you've shown already does a good job of preventing use of the database until the database is ready.  The problem it has is that it doesn't support multiple uses.  The 2nd callback won't fail because it got an uninitialized database.  It only fails after the database has been initialized because it gets the prior operation's result instead of a database.

There are two common options.  One is to stop having multiple uses.  This is not as absurd as it might sound.  For example:

```
def main():
    ...
    d_db_ready.addCallback(run_the_program)
    ...

def run_the_program(database):
    d_a = read_a_value_from_the_database(database)
    d_b = read_a_value_from_the_database(database)
    ...
```

Now the only callback on `d_db_ready` is `run_the_program` and `run_the_program` takes care of passing the database out where it needs to go.

The second option is to make your readiness API support multiple uses.  There are many different implementation approaches you can take here but they all center around breaking the result chaining feature of Deferred.  For example, you could do this:

```
def wait_for_db(callback):
    def safe_callback(database):
        try:
            callback(database)
        except:
            # logging or support an errback or something
        return database
    d_db_ready.addCallback(safe_callback)
```

`safe_callback` makes sure the result of `d_db_ready` is always the database, not some random callback's result.

There are much better implementations of this idea possible (for example, one that is still based on `Deferred` instead of giving up its affordances for passing around bare callbacks).  Hopefully this simple one gives you the general idea though.

Comment: Thank you greatly for your detailed reply @Jean-PaulCalderone.

Comment: The two patterns you described are great references.  Do you know if there is a collection of recommended Deferred patterns somewhere?  Something along the lines of "Design Patterns" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: I have added a Deferred-based implementation of your second option in my own answer below.  I hesitated to add it into your answer as I was not sure if that's the done thing on stackoverflow.  I would greatly appreciate your feedback if you have time and I'm happy to turn my answer in a community wiki if that's a good idea in your eyes.

Comment: I don't know of a good list of Deferred patterns, unfortunately.  I've often wished for such a thing as I frequently see the either the same patterns being reinvented in different places or the same anti-patterns getting adopted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the second option in @Jean-PaulCalderone's answer, here is an implementation based on Deferreds:

```
def get_database():
    d = Deferred()
    def when_ready(db):
        d.callback(db)
        return db
    d_db_ready.addCallback(when_ready)
    
    return d

get_database().addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database)
get_database().addCallback(read_a_value_from_the_database) # <--- works correctly

init_database()
```

Note that `d_db_ready` should now be considered private to the function `get_database()`, and should no longer be accessed by the user.

Comment: Nice.  Two suggestions.  (1) Look at `Deferred.chainDeferred` and see if you can figure out how to add good error handling behavior to `get_database`.  (2) Consider whether it would be beneficial to hide init_database and d_db_ready _inside_ `get_database` - or perhaps inside the instance state of a class.